# How to implement remember me functionality in spring mvc with time constraint

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i have created simple mvc login application  I am looking forward to implement remember me functionality with the time constraint like if the remember me is checked,the session should wait till 7 days and if the user doesn't check 
remember me the session it should destroy in 30 min, then check for session is null if it is null then it should  redirect it to login.jsp

i used this link https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-remember-me-example/ because am new spring i couldn't get

**login.jsp**

```
<form id="loginForm" role="form" action="login" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class=" col-xs-15 control-label">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail or Username"
                                            name="userName" type="text" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class=" col-xs-15 control-label">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                                            name="password" type="password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label> <input name="remember" type="checkbox"
                                        value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"
                                    value="login" /> <br>

                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        Registration Yourself <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="StudentSelfRegister.jsp">Student</a></li>                                      
                                        <li><a href="TeacherSelfRegister.jsp">Teacher</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <span><a href="javascript:void(0)"><u>Forgot your password ?</u></a></span>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                        </form>
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**AppInitializer**

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String authenticateUserLogin(@ModelAttribute User loginDTO) {
        if (loginDTO.getUserName().equals("admin") && loginDTO.getUserName().equals("123")) {
            return "Home";
        }
        return "Login";
    }
}
```

**Home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this

**controller**

```
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginRequestHandler(ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Account acc = checkCookie(request);
        if (acc == null) {
            modelMap.put("accountForm", new Account());
            return "login";
        }   
        else {          
            AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();
            if (accountModel.login(acc.getUsername(), acc.getPassword())) {
                session.setAttribute("username", acc.getUsername());
                return "welcome";
            } else {
                modelMap.put("errorMSg", "invalid login from cookie");
                return "login";
            }
        }       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginRequestHandler(@ModelAttribute("accountForm") Account account,ModelMap modelMap,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        AccountModel accountModel=new AccountModel();
        if(accountModel.login(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword()))
        {
            session.setAttribute("username", account.getUsername());
            if(request.getParameter("remember")!=null)
            {
                Cookie ckUsername=new Cookie("username",account.getUsername());
                ckUsername.setMaxAge(30);
                response.addCookie(ckUsername);
                Cookie ckPassword=new Cookie("password",account.getPassword());
                ckUsername.setMaxAge(30);
                response.addCookie(ckPassword);
            }
            return "welcome";
        }
        else
        {
            modelMap.put("errorMSg", "invalid login not from cookie");
            return "login";
        }
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        session.removeAttribute("username");
        for (Cookie ck:request.getCookies()) {
            if(ck.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("username")){
                ck.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(ck);
            }
            if(ck.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("password")){
                ck.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(ck);
            }
        }
        return "login";
    }


    public Account checkCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie [] cookies=request.getCookies();
        Account account=null;
        String username="",  password="";
        for (Cookie ck:cookies) {
            if(ck.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("username"))
                username=ck.getValue();
            if(ck.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
                password=ck.getValue();
        }
        if(!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty())
            account=new Account(username,password);
        return account;
    }
}
```

**In jsp**

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.username != null}">
   <c:redirect url = "http://localhost:8080/Test2/"/>
</c:if>
welcome ${sessionScope.username }
<br>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
```